# Is there a way to disable the app download option on flutter web?

Tags: flutter-web

When opening the application on a computer or browser in mobile a option for download or saving the page in desktop appear. There is some solution to disable this option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this to your `<script>` tag in your index.html:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it by passing `--pwa-strategy none` as a build argument:

```bash
flutter build web --pwa-strategy none
```

Answer (score -2):

The following article highlights how this can be achieved.

Essentially you need to type the following into the terminal in the root directory of your project `flutter config --no-enable-macos-desktop --no-enable-windows-desktop --no-enable-linux-desktop`.

If successful you should get the following output:

`Setting "enable-linux-desktop" value to "false". Setting "enable-macos-desktop" value to "false".   Setting "enable-windows-desktop" value to "false".`

To turn these settings on again you need to remove the `no`s from the command above.

https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-disable-web-and-desktop-support-in-flutter/