# What is flutter web "install app" and how to disable it?

Tags: flutter, web

We have a Flutter app deployed mostly as web.
When opened in Chrome on Mac, on the right side of the url bar, there is this "download" icon, and suggests to "install app". When clicked, seems to install some kind of local app, but not sure what this is.

What is it?
How to disable it?

[image]

Comment: Your app is a [PWA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_app). How to disable it depends on your app. It's possible that you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71113128/3784008).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to disable the app download option on flutter web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69577150/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-app-download-option-on-flutter-web)

Comment: thank you @anothermh but the `beforeinstallprompt` didn't help to disable the "install app"